# Indexing whole project directory with vim and coc-clangd

Tags: vim, clangd

Since few day I am trying to force *vim-coc* (with *coc-clangd*) to work properly with project. My test project is clonned bluez project. 
When I open`bluez/src/main.c` with vim (neovim in my case) most of autocompletion and goto definition works but unfortunately some of included headers like `#include "lib/bluetooth.h"` cannot be referenced because its location is in `bluez/lib/...`. 
How can I force vim-coc to treat main bluez directory as master dir for indexer?

Answer (score 2):

Can you build the project? If you can, run command:`bear make`(bear need to be installed).
After you run the command, you will see a file named "compile_commands.json".
Then completion might be able to work.